# Vaadin: center componet in Layout dont work with setSizeFull just with static values?

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a panel inside a layout and tried to center it in the middle:

1. Doesn't work if layout is 100% X 100% (setSizeFull). Panel is place in the top left of the Window.

But,

2. If I asign a static value setWidht("500px") the panel is place in the center of the 500px.

Why or how can I center a panel in a Layout with a setSizeFull property?

Some pseudo-code:

```
class MyVaadinUI 
   init method 
       setContent(new Login());
```

and

```
class Login extends CustomComponent  // Vaadin Composite
    Login() // constructor
       vLayout.setComponentAlignment(panel, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);

       // Code for VerticalLayout and panel is autogenerate by wysiwyg editor
       //the problem if that if vlayout is set with 100% x 100% (setSizefull)    
       //the panel is place in the top-left corner BUT if a set a static value 
       // 1280x800 it is correct place in the middle center
```

Comment: What layout?. Please post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `Panel` in the `layout` and you have called `layout.setSizeFull()`.

You can use [`#setComponentAlignment`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractOrderedLayout.html#setComponentAlignment(com.vaadin.ui.Component,%20com.vaadin.ui.Alignment)) this,

```
VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();//For example
layout.setSizeFull()
layout.addComponent(panel);//Your panel
layout.setComponentAlignment(panel, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
```

---

***EDIT***

I think you have not called `setSizeFull()` on your `MainUI` class.You have added `setSizeFull` on `LogIn`.You should fix the height and width of `LogIn` and add `this.setSizeFull()` to the `MainUI`.

Comment: I did exactly that but if a set layout.setSizeFull() it doesnt works I must set a static size to the layout: layout.setWidth("1280px") and layout.setHeight("800px"). I m using vaadin maven archetype 7.1.15 and the using the vaadin wysiwyg editor.

Comment: Yes, it was that ,I did not add setSizeFull(); on MainUI-

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution. According to [this](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/249127/249236)  "A layout with undefined size can't contain a component with relative size." So adding a setSizeFull to the UI works:

```
class MyVaadinUI 
   init method 
       this.setSizeFull();
       setContent(new Login());
```